# Python - Parent method don't acess the value of variable children

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

Hi I'm having a problem in this classes I created the parent class extracao_nia with the method aplica_extracao for having the similar part of the execution that I use in others class and the diferent part is in the transform method definined in the children class
but I'm having an issue that the variables that I defined as list() are Null variable when I execute the code:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

```
class extracao_nia:

def __init__(self, d=1, h=1, m=15):
    self._data_base = "database"
    self.UM_DIA = datetime.timedelta(days=d)
    self.UMA_HORA = datetime.timedelta(hours=h)
    self.INTERVALO = datetime.timedelta(minutes=m)

@property
def data_base(self):
    return self._data_base

def aplica_extracao(self, SQL):

    fim_intervalo = self.inicio + self.INTERVALO#
    pbar = self.cria_prog_bar(SQL)#
    while (fim_intervalo <= self.FIM):#
        self.connector.execute(SQL,(self.inicio.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'),fim_intervalo.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')))#
        for log in self.connector:#
            self.transforma(log)
            
        self.inicio = fim_intervalo
        fim_intervalo = self.inicio + self.INTERVALO


class usuarios_unicos(extracao_nia):

def __init__(self, d=1, h=1, m=15, file='nodes.json'):

    self._data_base = "database"
    self.UM_DIA = datetime.timedelta(days=d)
    self.UMA_HORA = datetime.timedelta(hours=h)
    self.INTERVALO = datetime.timedelta(minutes=m)
    self.file = file
    self.ids = list()
    self.nodes = list()
    self.list_cpf = list()

def transforma(self, log):
    context = json.loads(log[0])['context']
    output = json.loads(log[0])['output']

    try:
        nr_cpf = context['dadosDinamicos']['nrCpf']
        conversation_id = context['conversation_id']
        nodes_visited = output['output_watson']['nodes_visited']
        i = self.ids.index(conversation_id)
        atual = len(self.nodes[i])
        novo = len(nodes_visited)
        if novo > atual:
            nodes[i] = nodes_visited
            
    except KeyError:
        pass

    except ValueError:
        self.ids.append(conversation_id)
        self.nodes = self.nodes.append(nodes_visited)
        self.list_cpf = self.list_cpf.append(nr_cpf)
```

Comment: Repair the indentation of the code and show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list.append` returns `None` since it is an in-place operation, so

```
self.nodes = self.nodes.append(nodes_visited)
```

will result in `self.nodes` being assigned `None`. Instead you can just use

```
self.nodes += nodes_visited
```